# LoaderMax - как сделать очередь с приоритетами?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Может кто-нибудь показать в коде, как сделать тоже самое - [LoaderMax_Demo.swf](http://www.greensock.com/as/LoaderMax/LoaderMax_Demo.swf)
. Больше всего меня интересует, создается ли всего один экземпляр ImageLoader и в него передается массив значений очередей и приоритетов или для каждой картинки отдельный экземпляр и отдельные значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для каждой картинки создается экземпляр ImageLoader, причем создаете вы его сами.
- Очередь создается автоматически, просто наиболее приоритетные добавляйте раньше в очередь.
- Элемент списка очереди можно подвинуть повысив приоритет, например

  LoaderMax.prioritize("photo1"); // В начало очереди.

или

```
queue.insert( new ImageLoader("img/photo.jpg"), 2); // В 2-й номер очереди.
```

Comment: @ShockWave: Вы меня успокоили, а то в коде я подтверждения найти не мог, но сомнения все равно оставались, ведь автор так сильно любит передавать все объекты массивами. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Кстати, используя один и тот же Loader не сильно выигрываешь в памяти и производительности. Загрузчик все равно занимает память контентом, той же bitmap, а обвязка на каждый уходит всего по 5-10 килобайт.

Comment: @ShockWave: Спасибо, буду знать, но я немного с другой целью интересовался. И задам Вам ещё... Нет, я лучше создам ещё тему, раз тут награды то думаю Вам так лучше будет.